# wiql using username and password

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, wiql

Can we query TFS database by mentioning server name, user name and password in WIQL string ?

i see that it is possible to first authenticate server from c# code and then use that info to query against the server but would like to know if we can even pass the credentials in wiql string.

we want to maintain wiql strings as text files on disk and dynamically query as needed.

Answer (score 0):

from visual studio, connect to TFS, create a query and save to disk. That file will have .wiq extension. Double-clicking this file brings up query. These files can be parsed as xml and can be maintained separately.